# Parse .xlsx with Python and gather statistic of contents from rows and columns

Tags: python, excel, parsing, xlsx, xlrd

I have .xlsx file which looks like this:

```
  ID      Column1    Column2    Column3   ...

  123      Free       BLUE       XX
  333       NA        GREEN      X
  445      BUSY       BLUE       XX
  665      FREE       BLUE       XXX
  332       NA        RED        X
  297      FREE       BLUE       XXXX 
  ...      ...        ...        ...
```

So I have to make a python script that will load this file and parse it and give me all ID's which for example have Column1 FREE. Have found out that I can use  libraries like xlrd, pandas, Openpyxl etc.. but still cannot achive what I need.

My current try with xlrd is like this:

```
  file_location = 'location'
    workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(file_location)
    
    sheet = workbook.sheet_by_name('wanted_sheet')
    
    IDs = []
    col1 = []
    for id in sheet.col_values(0):
        IDs.append(id)
    
    for state in sheet.col_values(1):
       if state == 'FREE':
         col1.append(state)
```

Now need to connect somehow this state with corresponding ID... What would be best approach to do this?

Comment: Try using a dictionary

Comment: Do you want to filter out the rows while reading the file, or do you want to get all the contents, and then apply your filter, perhaps each time with different criteria?

Comment: I think it would be better case to get all contents and then adapt criteria, good point

Comment: I am trying something like, take col1[], for every item in that list find row number, then put with it value  from same row but ID column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1**

Use `pandas`. You already have an answer by @wenyongzhou.

**Option 2**

If for any reasons you have to do without `pandas`, just use `openpyxl` or another library and read the rows in a `dict`. In order to have some filtering options we may define a little function:

```
wb=load_workbook("yourfile.xlsx")
ws=wb.active

def filter_rows(ws, filtercolumn, filtervalue):
    headers = [h.value for h in next(ws.rows)]
    filterindex = headers.index(filtercolumn)
    return {r[0].value : r[filterindex].value for r in ws.rows if r[filterindex].value == filtervalue}

filter_rows(ws,"Column1","FREE")
{665: 'FREE', 297: 'FREE'}

filter_rows(ws,"Column2","BLUE")
{123: 'BLUE', 445: 'BLUE', 665: 'BLUE', 297: 'BLUE'}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel(
    io = "R:/x.xlsx" ,
    # sheet_name = 0 , # 1st sheet ,
    sheet_name = "Sheet1" ,
    )

df[ ( df["Column1"]=="Free" ) | ( df["Column1"]=="FREE" ) ]
```

Adjust your filepath and sheetname as required.